# Android: bad animation framerate when fading screen

Tags: android, animation, alpha

I have simple task: fade screen (+ other actions, but it doesnt matter now) when something happens (say, button pressed).
My minSDKVersion is 11. I do it in this way: activity layout contains a view:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/bgFadingView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alpha="0"
    android:background="@android:color/black" />
```

and method where I fade screen is as follows:

```
protected void fadeBGView(boolean fadeIn)
{
    ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(bgFadingView, "alpha", fadeIn ? 0.75f : 0f); //bgFadingView is initialized via findViewById(R.id.bgFadingView);
    animator.setDuration(1000);
    animator.start();
}
```

in other words, I have black view, which occupies the whole screen and when I need to fadeIn, I change view's alpha from 0 to 0.75.

The problem is that it works with bad framerate... I see fading animation frame by frame - it works at about 15fps. What am I doing wrong? Android system fading works much more smoothly - I want to archieve the same result or close. How to?

Comment: You can enable hardware acceleration if you're truly going to ever target API 11+. The system animations use it. That will most likely fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was:

```
ObjectAnimator.setFrameDelay(10);
```

default frame delay was too long, so my animations didnt work smoothly. The problem was not due to device performance limitations.